# Negative Numbers at Risk; Survfit doubling my subject sample size; Competing Risks Model

Tags: r, survival

I'm evaluating competing risks of mortality of birds due to various causes (snakes, mammals, hawks, other) with staggered entry. I have 120 individuals; 60 entered at time 0 and 60 at time 63; I ran survcheck in the R survival package. The transitions appear correct. Has anyone experienced this? Is it a function of the staggered entry? How can it be fixed?

This appear correct

`Call:
survcheck(formula = Surv(start, stop, Mortfac) ~ 1, data = mymerge2,
id = Band, timefix = T)

Unique identifiers       Observations        Transitions
120              16314                 41

Transitions table:
to
from        Avian Mammalian Other Snake (censored)
(s0)         18        12     2     9         79
Avian         0         0     0     0          0
Mammalian     0         0     0     0          0
Other         0         0     0     0          0
Snake         0         0     0     0          0

Number of subjects with 0, 1, ... transitions to each state:
count
state         0  1
Avian     102 18
Mammalian 108 12
Other     118  2
Snake     111  9
(any)      79 41`

I have no flags when calling the survfit object. However, when running the model receive the Warning:

`"Warning message: In cbind(Y[-(1 + e2), 1], Y[-e2, -1]) : number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"`

When reviewing the output, the number at risk is negative at the first event and probabilities are incorrect.

`Call: survfit(formula = Surv(start, stop, Mortfac) ~ 1, data = mymerge2,
id = Band)

time n.risk n.event Pr((s0)) Pr(Avian) Pr(Mammalian) Pr(Other) Pr(Snake)
6    -19       1    1.000      0.00          1.00   0.00000    0.0000
14    -14       1    1.000      1.00          1.00   0.00000    0.0000
25     -9       1    1.000      2.00          1.00   0.00000    0.0000
69      5       1    0.800      2.20          1.00   0.00000    0.0000
73     16       1    0.750      2.20          1.00   0.00000    0.0500
76     18       1    0.708      2.24          1.00   0.00000    0.0500`

Doubled number at risk, now

`Call: survfit(formula = Surv(start, stop, Mortfac) ~ 1, data = mymerge2,
id = Band)

```
        n nevent      rmean*
```

(s0)      240      0 129.0403379
Avian     240     18 374.5939873
Mammalian 240     12 195.7509905
Other     240      2   0.4003824
Snake     240      9   7.2143019
*restricted mean time in state (max time = 188 )`

I've edited inputs for id to change from numeric to factor, and various other simple inputs changes. No difference. When running as a simple KM or Cox model where event is dead or alive, the numbers at risk and number of events over time are correct.

I've also tried cumulative incidence functions which do not appear to give correct numbers. If the number at risk is 120 and 18 were killed by avian, then I would expect the values on the Y axis to be much larger than the following. Cuminc doesn't allow for ID variable, which may be the issue for that.

[image]